# Is there a way to filter an array created from an AJAX query?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I have a query that runs to fill a table with entries in a Sharepoint list - What I'm trying to do is filter this list based on the contents of specific fields in the list.  Is this possible using just one list and JavaScript, or will I need to create different views and query each of them based on which options are selected?

```js
function getIncidents(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "SharepointURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Incident List')/items?$select=Title,Id,Priority,IncidentStart,IncidentStatus,IncidentTitle,UpdateResolution,ImpactedArea",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
  success: function (data) {
   var dResponse = data.d.results;
   var results = document.getElementById('Results');
   results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Incident<br>Reference</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td>Priority</td><td style='width:20px;'></td><td>Start Time</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Issue</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Latest Update</td><td style='width:20px'></td></tr>";
   for(var obj in dResponse){
    results.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-size:10pt'><td>"+dResponse[obj].Title+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].Priority+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].IncidentStart+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].IncidentTitle+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].UpdateResolution+"</td></tr>";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Get Incidents" onclick="getIncidents()">
<table id="Results">
</table>
```

The fields I'm trying to filter by are `Incident Satus` and `Impacted Area`, which I'm intending on not displaying on the front screen, but I call it so that I can use it to filter.

Comment: How does `dResponse` look like?

Comment: You can use .filter() or .grep() API for filter out Array

Comment: From the code it looks like `dResponse` is an array of objects, so you can simply call [`.filter(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on it. If the API supports it, you should filter server-side though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "filter" in this case.  Do you mean that you want to tell the server to only return those fields and no others?  You're using other fields in the response though.  And the query sent to the server is explcitly indicating the fields you want.  Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Yes, the dResponse is a Json array of objects pulled from the SharePoint list - and by filtering, I only want to display items based on whether the contents of the field being filtered contains specific words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `filter` function on your `dResponse` array. You didn't specify what filter you wanted but here is a basic example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getIncidents(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://office4.bt.com/sites/ccim/Mobile/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Incident List')/items?$select=Title,Id,Priority,IncidentStart,IncidentStatus,IncidentTitle,UpdateResolution,ImpactedArea",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
  success: function (data) {
   var dResponse = data.d.results;
   // we filter the data before using it.
   // we use const because we do not plan on reassigning the variable.
   const filteredResponse = dResponse.filter((item) => item.someFilteringData);

   var results = document.getElementById('Results');
   results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Incident<br>Reference</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td>Priority</td><td style='width:20px;'></td><td>Start Time</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Issue</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Latest Update</td><td style='width:20px'></td></tr>";
   for(var obj in filteredResponse){
    results.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-size:10pt'><td>"+filteredResponse [obj].Title+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].Priority+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].IncidentStart+"</td><td></td><td>"+filteredResponse [obj].IncidentTitle+"</td><td></td><td>"+dResponse[obj].UpdateResolution+"</td></tr>";
   }
  }
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: for this solution, with ```dResponse.filter((item) => item.someFilteringData);``` - is ```(item)``` referring to the field, i.e. Reference, Start Time, etc. and ```item.someFilteringData``` referring to the content I want to filter by?  Does this require an exact match, or will it filter if the field only 'contains' the value given?

Comment: The `filter` function takes a callback, in the callback you have access to the current item. You can check whatever you want with this item as long as your function is returning a boolean. if this boolean is true, the item will be include in the output. If not, it will be exclude. @GetWhimsical

Answer (score 0):

So in the end you want to filter an array of objects by one or more object properties? Yes, that's easy.

```
let myArray = [ {a: 10, b: 'red'}, {a: 20, b: 'green'} ]
let filteredArray = myArray.filter(x=>x.b=='green')
```

A more elegant way (if possible) would be to send parameters to your API and filter server-side.